# knockout js hiding button text

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I am using knockoutjs to send ajax call and successfully am able to do that but when I click on update button the text on button gets to hide.

```
<div class="field-group">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('form-fields') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <button type="submit" data-bind="click: update" class="action">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'update'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Can someone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether any CSS styles are getting applied when you hover or click on the button.